# Post order in layout (wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I made the layout for blog and styled each post in block. I have problem with display order of post.
I use standard loop:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=317&showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

For ex. - I have 4 posts with dates 27.04, 26.04, 25.04, 24.04.
Now it shows:
[image]

I'd like to display it like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="center">
        <div class="center_top">
            <div class="content_title">
                <?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display')) { bcn_display(); }?>
            </div>
            <div class="back_btn"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Powrót</a></div>
        </div>
<div id="center">
    <div class="center_top">
        <article class="blog_post">

        <?php query_posts('cat=317&showposts=6'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post_blog">
        <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
            <div class="wpis_title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><font color="black" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><?php the_title(); ?></font></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
        <small><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></small>
        <br><br>

        <div class="blog_left_side">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        }
        ?></a>
        </div>

        <div class="entry">
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $num_words = 30, $more = null ); ?></p>
        </div><div class="news_read_more">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"> &raquo; Czytaj więcej</a>
                    </div>
    </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->


            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </article>
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Starsze wpisy') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Nowsze wpisy &raquo;') ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here's the css:

```
.post_blog {
border: 1px solid #F1EBEB;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 300px;
width: 40%;
float: left;
margin-left: 40px;
}

.blog_left_side {
float:left;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.wpis_title {
margin-top: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 22px;
}

.wpis_title a {
text-decoration:none;
}

article.blog_post {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 15px 15px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    box-shadow: inset 15px 15px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    padding:20px;
    height:900px;
}

.news_read_more {
text-align: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a php problem and not just a css one? (if you output them one under the other are they still not in the right order?) Because we would need the CSS code.

Comment: Try to modify the quesry like this:  <?php query_posts('cat=317&showposts=6&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>

Comment: @Oylex you may be right. I edited post and paste the css. Could you check it?